# What is maximum Scale for the decimal.

Tags: oracle, teradata

What is maximum Scale  for the decimal. I know that the Legal values for precision range from 1 to 38, and legal values for scale range from -84 to 127.
In other words, how can we give 127  or -84 in the scale  value ?
For example :
select  cast (12345678912345678912345678912.123456789  AS decimal(38,9)) from dual;

I cannot give more than 9 scale. Even If i place my decimal at any postion I cannot give more than 38 (may be less) so how come scale ranges from -84 to 127.

Can anyone quote example for maximum scale ?
Note: this question is database independent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most DBMSes a `DECIMAL` supports up to 38 *digits*, i.e. both the *precision* and the *scale* are limited to 38 digits, the ranges are `decimal(38,0)` to `decimal(38,38)`.

You seem to confuse it with Oracle's `NUMBER` which is a kind of hybrid between `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL`. In Teradata it supports a range from `1e-130` to `9.99999999e125`, but the precision is still limited to 38 digits.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. Actually I m extracting data from teradata and the column has float data type , which I m trying to cast as CHAR(500)  [ to be safer side]  but business side technical team advised me to use decimal rather than CHAR,  now my confusion is  what max values (especially scale as precision is 38) I should take while extracting the records using fexp.  Also would you suggest me to still use CHAR  rather  decimal  (as our  migration is lift & shift they want exact data in target system (which is oracle) ?

Comment: @ClearThoughts: No, I would consider strings use as worst case. Oracle supports FLOAT, but as this stored as a NUMBER internally, I would use NUMBER.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Could you please advise how should I use (in terms of syntax) this number, while extracting the data from terdata  for this float column. Currently I m using  : cast(fval as  char(500)  .. could you please recommend the cast for number  [ like I said i know how to cast with decimal but my dilemma is the scale portion as I m not sure the scale for float ] . Awaiting your prompt reply. Also FYI  I'm extracting from teradata as a flat file and then loading that flat file to oracle

Comment: @ClearThoughts: Assuming you export a CSV format it's already converted to a string by Teradata (or the export utility), the default format will be `-9.99999999999999E-999`. I would prefer the NUMBER format -> Teradata supports `TO_CHAR(myfloat)`.

Comment: I m sorry for bothering you.I m using flat file (.txt). AlsoI believe I m doing the same thing i.e  in my fexp im casting to CHAR but I believe you said its better to use  NUMBER. So essentially I agree with you and want to cast the FLOAT  to number  but the dilemma is the scale portion. Could you please advise?

Comment: @ClearThoughts: Why CHAR, do you need a fixed format? Otherwise `TO_CHAR` is fine, no need to care about the scale, the format is flexible and switches to scientific notation when neccessary. You could `CAST(TO_CHAR(...) AS CHAR(40))` (`CHAR(40)` is the maximum length of the NUMBER format)

Comment: Currently I m using this in my fast export script :  COALESCE (CAST("MYCOLUMN"  as  CHAR(500)),' ')                                                  Is this what you would recommend too ?   where MYCLOLUMN is float data type. My confusion is you said you recommend NUMBER  over char. SO I want you to kindly recommend how can I use NUMBER (if you are not  recommending  the approach I m using). Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Just to add on  I m not looking for any fixed format... I want float value to be exactly extracted and loaded in my target system.

Comment: @ClearThoughts: Export `TO_CHAR(my_float_column)` from Teradata and load it into a `NUMBER` on Oracle

Comment: Gotcha .. Thank you so much. Really appreciate your patient and quick response.